# валидатор выдает ошибку в скрипте как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, валидация

выдает вот эту ошибку как исправить?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас script идет после закрытого тега body. Тег script должен быть внутри body, а не за его пределами.